# Rails 4.1 and exception_notification-rake gem causing uninitialized constant ExceptionNotification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, exception-notification

I've upgraded to Rails 4.1 and am trying to set up the exception_notification-rake gem to notify me by email of failed rake tasks.

In my Gemfile, I have `gem 'exception_notification-rake'`.

In `development.rb`, I have the following:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # Specify what domain to use for mailer URLs
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "localhost:3000"}
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address              => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port                 => 587,
      :domain               => 'gmail.com',
      :user_name            => Rails.application.secrets.email['user'],
      :password             => Rails.application.secrets.email['pass'],
      :authentication       => 'login',
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.after_initialize do
    Bullet.enable = true
    Bullet.alert = true
    Bullet.bullet_logger = true
    Bullet.console = true
    # Bullet.growl = true
    Bullet.rails_logger = true
    Bullet.add_footer = true
  end

  config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,
    :ignore_if => lambda { |env, exception| !env[:rake?] },
    :email => {
      :sender_address => %{"notifier" myemail@gmail.com},
      :exception_recipients => %w(myemail@gmail.com)
    }
    ExceptionNotifier::Rake.configure
end
```

As you can see, I'm passing in the user and password using Rails 4.1's secrets.yml file.
When I try starting up my Rails server, I get the following error:

```
/development.rb:52:in `
block in <top (required)>': uninitialized constant ExceptionNotification (NameError)
```

I'm guessing this is a bug in the exception_notification-rake gem which calls a previous version of the exception_notification, but I'm not sure. Any help with this would be appreciated!

Thanks :)

**Update:**

I've [notified the exception_notification-rake gem developer](https://github.com/nikhaldi/exception_notification-rake/issues/6) about this. I have all the prerequisite gems and have a fairly vanilla setup so I think this might be a bug that needs to be fixed for Rails 4.1

Comment: This feels like a very obvious thing to ask but are you sure you ran `bundle update` and `bundle install` and have you got `gem 'exception_notification'` in your gemfile as well as `gem 'exception_notification-rake`?

Comment: Yep, done all that. Still not working, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in this [issue](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification/issues/223) the current, published, version of `ExceptionNotification` does not work with rails 4.1

Until the new version is released, you can just use the master version. In your `Gemfile` include your gem as follows:

```
gem 'exception_notification', github: 'smartinez87/exception_notification'
```

The maintainer has released a rc-version, which you can use as follows

```
gem 'exception_notification', '4.1.0.rc1'
```

Once the new gem version is released, you can switch to the released version (4.1.0). This should not take too long I guess ;)

Comment: When I try adding `gem 'exception_notification', github: 'smartinez87/exception_notification'` to my Gemfile, I get the following error: `Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "exception_notification": In Gemfile: exception_notification-rake (>= 0) ruby depends on exception_notification (~> 3.0.0) ruby`

Comment: You have to update your version of `exception_notification-rake` as well. Note: both gems are now released, so you do not have to refer to the github anymore, just install the latest version (4.0.1). I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Ok. I was mistaken (4.0.1 and 4.1.0 look similar). You seem to have an old version of `exception_notification-rake`. I see the current version (0.1.2) depends on `exception_notification` with version `~> 4.0.1` so I hope that would work (the `~>` means only minor changes, non-breaking are allowed) so I am not sure it will support a `4.1.0.rc` version at all. I am guessing it does not, so the gem author should relax that dependency (e.g. use `> 4.0.1` instead), or release a new version.

Comment: I'm the maintainer of `exception_notification-rake`. Thanks for tracking down this issue. I pushed a new version (0.2.0.rc1) that has the dependencies rejiggered to work with Rails 4.1 and exception_notification 4.1.